# In each case, find elements $a$ and $b$ from a group such that if $|a|=2, |b|= 2$...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In each case, find elements $a$ and $b$ from a group such that if $|a|=2, |b|= 2$:

a.) $|ab|=3$
b.) $|ab|=4$
c.) $|ab|=5$

Any hints on how to approach this, I'm a little confused...

Comment: Which groups have you learned about?

Comment: The question is in a chapter about subgroup tests and subgroups... so it's basically the beginning of the book on abstract algebra. I know about dihedral groups, cyclic groups, $Z_n$, $U(n)$ etc.

Comment: Have you considered using a symmetric group $S_n$? Do you know which elements have order 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bijective maps on $Z_n$ and $f(x)=-x, g(x)=-x-1$

or as Micheal said $(a, b)$, $(b, c)$ has order $2$ but $(a, b)(b, c)=(a, b, c)$ has order $3$.....

Answer (score 0):

Another answer here is just to take a rotation $R_{360/n}$ in $D_n$ and some arbitrary reflection $F_1$ in $D_n$. Note products of rotations and reflections are reflections, so $F_1R_{360/n}=F_2$ is some reflection $F_2$ in $D_n$.

All reflections in $D_n$ have order $2$ and $F_1F_2=R_{360/n}$, so $|F_1|=|F_2|=2$ and $|F_1F_2|=|R_{360/n}|=n$.